# Provide SSL certificate in Docker image from private registry or create one at every start?

Tags: docker, ssl, ssl-certificate, microservices, lets-encrypt

I'm looking for an advice on best practices regarding the provision of a SSL certificate (from letsencrypt.org) in a Docker image or creation of the certificate on each start of the container.

There're a lot of howtos and questions on the site regarding the creation of the certificate however, I can't wrap my head around neither of the idea to store the certificate in the Docker image and upload it to a registry protected with credentials nor to create the certificate on every start of the image (might be often because I'm designing microservices).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to generate cert on every container start, then you will hit LE rate limits soon https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/ => save certs to the persistent storage and reuse them.